# How do I serve the initial page in websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

Ok so my question is concerning the websockets api...NOT socket.io. `npm install websocket`

Here's my problem.

I have written a little websockets server that can receive a message, interpret the textual message and send it back with a little extra text. Simple enough.

The message comes from an index.html file with a javascript...script written in it. Everything works as expected. The node server runs locally on my machine and when I want to test it out I just start the server then double click the index.html file which runs the script, which starts a new connection with node and done.

What I want is to be able to navigate my browser to "localhost" and the server start by giving  the client the index.html file, which in turn will establish a connection with the server.

How can the user get the index.html file by simply navigating to a url (localhost in my case), if a connection is required to get the index.html file. In Socket.io it looks like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {});
```

If my question is still unclear here is a rewording: A user needs to be able to go to my url (localhost since node is running locally) and receive index.html. Like, all requests to the root receive an index.html file within a public directory.

Comment: You should really specify the language.

Comment: This question is more directed towards people who actually do know what nodejs and the websockets api are.

Comment: Then you should tag the question with "node.js".  I have done so.

Comment: Note that in the example code you've provided (`app.use`, `app.get(...)`), you're actually using [Express](http://expressjs.com/), not socket.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [module](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) you are using includes a [complete example](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/example/whiteboard/whiteboard.js)  of how to use it with Express.  It looks like it's written for the Express 2 API, so you have to [tweak it](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) if you're using Express 3:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});

server.listen(80);
```

Comment: Oh ok I gotcha. So trying to separate the two was a bad idea. I guess I didn't really think about trying to let both express and websocket work in harmony. I +1'ed you thanks josh.